# Does Whatsapp store my contacts on its server to implement last seen?

Tags: android, xmpp, whatsapp

Whatsapp provides 3 options for whom to show my last seen: Everyone, My Contacts, Nobody. Everyone and Nobody are pretty straight forwards, would be implemented by setting a flag in server database.

But when it comes to showing my last seen to My Contacts, when someone requests server for my last seen, how does server know that the person is in my contacts are not?

Comment: this is not right place to ask this question, but your answer is yes,

Comment: @shayanpourvatan thanks, please can you tell where can this question be asked?

Comment: welcome, I don't know where is right place, but in this site we ask programming problem.